# AJAX inside selectonemenu not calling target on every update

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu and I want that whenever the value changes it goes to a specific method in my bean.

Here is my code:

```
        <p:selectOneMenu id="qupdate" value="#{o.pquantity}">

<f:selectItem styleClass="form-control"
                            itemLabel="-- SELECT QUANTITY -- " itemValue=""
                            noSelectionOption="true" />

                        <f:selectItems  value="#{selectonemenu.quantoptions}" var="f"
                            itemLabel="#{f}" itemValue="#{f}" />


                     <p:ajax   process="@this" update=":carticon" execute="qupdate" event="change"
                            listener="#{MyBean.quantitychange(o.pquantity, o.id)}" /> 


                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I tried to change and use different parameters of ajax but still it's not working as it's supposed to

Comment: Why do you pass arguments to the listener? The fields should be populated when doing ajax so it should not be needed to pass them as a paramenter. Oh and **ALWAYS** post a [mcve] and relevant version info

Comment: And if it is not every update, try to determine how it is behaving. Every other update? Not the first but then every other? The first and every other?

Comment: execute is not a vaid property of p:ajax